# nodejs daemon wrong architecture

Tags: macos, node.js, daemon

I'm trying to run 'dali' a highcharts exporter from nodejs on my Mac under OSX Mountain Lion

I'm getting the following error:

```
module.js:485
    process.dlopen(filename, module.exports);
      ^
Error: dlopen(/Users/greg/node_modules/daemon/lib/daemon.v0.8.8.node, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Users/greg/node_modules/daemon/lib/daemon.v0.8.8.node: mach-o, but wrong architecture
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:485:11)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
at require (module.js:378:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/greg/node_modules/daemon/lib/daemon.js:12:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

The key part is: "wrong architecture"

If I run:

```
lipo -info /Users/greg/node_modules/daemon/lib/daemon.v0.8.8.node
```

It returns:

```
Non-fat file: /Users/greg/node_modules/daemon/lib/daemon.v0.8.8.node is architecture: i386
```

I'm guessing a x64 version is requried.

How do I get and install the 64 bit version of this lib?

Comment: You will probably have to build it from source.  I'd offer more advice, but I cannot seem to get the project page at the moment.  When NPM is back up, check its page for a link to Github or similar.  Then check there for the source and instructions for building.

Comment: @Brad I looked up the npm database and found the git url and then did this:
    npm install git://github.com/indexzero/daemon.node.git
Installed ok but I still get the same error when I run my app.
Is this how I am supposed to install from source?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this dialog took place about a month ago or so.  I have the same problem as the original poster on running a nodejs add-on written in C++.

But, lipo is used on universal file formats to create a single architecture file.  I am pretty sure that the message "Non-fat file..." is saying that the file IS NOT in a universal (fat) file format.  Since lipo only accepts fat files, lipo has no work to do on the file.

I have delved into the mach-o binary a bit and looked at the header.  The file is marked a a mach bundle and that is not what I expected.

I built my file via the NodeJS node-waf program with a wscript build file.  Currently, my problem has not been resolved.  I am new to both NodeJS and using WAF wscript files for building.